# mongodb query via php 7 failing silently?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-7

I have the following test code to see if my php server is configured properly to query a mongo database:

```
<?php
//http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-query.php/

$mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://127.0.0.1/widget:27017');
$id           = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId("582f629a6b6347a422abb8ad");
$filter      = ['_id' => $id];
$options = [];

$query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows   = $mongo->executeQuery('db.new_widgets', $query); 
var_dump($query);
foreach ($rows as $document) {
  var_dump($document);
}

?>
```

When I run this, no documents are returned. 
this is what I see in the mongo log:

```
2017-04-19T15:06:51.562+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:56870 #17 (9 connections now open)
2017-04-19T15:06:51.562+0000 I NETWORK  [conn17] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:56870 conn17: { driver: { name: "mongoc / ext-mongodb:PHP", version: "1.5.5 / 1.2.8" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Linux", version: "3.5.0", architecture: "x86_64" }, platform: "cfg=0x30c9 posix=200809 stdc=201112 CC=GCC 6.3.0 CFLAGS="-Os -fomit-frame-pointer" LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed" / PHP 7.1.3" }
```

There are no errors in the apache error log.

On the web page, as far as the $query dump, this is what I see:

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Query)#3 (3) { ["filter"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID)#5 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "582f629a6b6347a422abb8ad" } } ["options"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (0) { } ["readConcern"]=> NULL }
```

When I try the same query via the mongo shell / command line, i get the test record back no problems. 
Just wondering what I'm missing. 
I'm running php7 with mongodb 3.4

I'm currently looking into whether or not mongo has verbose logging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the connection string to look like this instead:

```
 $mongo new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
```

And then the query:

```
 $rows   = $mongo->executeQuery('widgets.new_widgets', $query);
```

Comment: Hi dot , i am not able to find doc. for php7 with new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager . can you please share any link with me

Comment: I actually started with this link but ... all functions have very less examples ....